# Chrome extension: looking for simplest way to receive messages from local application?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, websocket, webserver

I‘m looking for a way to expand an existing Google Chrome JS extension through the possibility for receive the short string messages from an local windows application.

What is the simplest solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve, but `window.postMessage` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: What about [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging)?